# NIFI Executescript UTC Error for unsupported operand type "+" in java.sql.Timestamp and timedelta

Tags: datetime, apache-nifi, jython, timedelta, execute-script

I am trying to split a flowfile into multiple flow files on the basis of adding a month to a date which i am getting in the coming flowfile.

eg. 
{"to":"2019-12-31T00:00:00Z","from":"2019-03-19T15:36:48Z"}
be the dates i am getting in a flowfile . so i have to split this single flow file into 11 flowfiles with date ranges like

```
{"to":"2019-04-19","from":"2019-03-19"}
{"to":"2019-05-19","from":"2019-04-19"} 
{"to":"2019-06-19","from":"2019-05-19"}
....... and so till
{"to":"2019-12-31","from":"2019-12-19"} .
```

i have been trying with example inputs to split files with this into day wise flowfiles:

`

```
 begin = '2018-02-15'
 end = '2018-04-23'
 dt_start = datetime.strptime(begin, '%Y-%m-%d')
 dt_end = datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')
 one_day = timedelta(days = 1)
 start_dates = [dt_start]
 end_dates = []
 today = dt_start
 while today <= dt_end:
     tomorrow = today + one_day
 print(tomorrow)
```

`

but i get a error in my Execute script processor. [nifi flow screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbbF2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Jython, you may have to cast `today` to some Jython/Python time variable or call `today.getTime()` in order to do arithmetic operations on it.

Comment: I used 'today.getTime()' but it changes the time into long which is again giving unsupported operand for long and timedelta

Comment: I'm not a Python expert but I think you'll need to convert the long into a datetime so you can add the timedelta, perhaps with `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(myNumber)`